# session.destroy in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a log out for my app and in my controller this piece of code is not working. Any solution would be helpful.

```
def destroy
  @user = user.find(params[:id])
  @user.destroy
end
```

This is my destroy method in my sessions controller(the fact that i am destroying my user in my sessions controller might be the problem)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

    def create
      @user = User.create(password: params[:password],
                          email: params[:email],
                          firstname: params[:firstname], 
                          lastname: params[:lastname])
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Fubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root :to => 'static#welcome'
  resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :show]
  resources :session, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :studios 
end
```

Routes file

> uninitialized constant SessionController

is the error im getting

Comment: You probably don't want to delete the user each time he logs out. That would require the user to register/signup each time he wants to visit the website again after logging out. If you're new to rails I suggest you look for resources online which explain how to create a login/logout system with sessions. My recommendation is Michael Hartl's 'Ruby on Rails tutorial', but most resources out there will do. Attempting to reinvent the wheel for things like this will just lead to wasted time and frustration.

Comment: You may want to look at pre-existing solutions like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) before rolling your own. Even if you don't use them, you can get ideas on how to implement your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't `destroy` your user. It deletes it from the database, you want them to be able to login again without creating a new user right?

You need to update your `routes.rb` file to be:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Fubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root :to => 'static#welcome'
  resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :show]
  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy] # changed to sessions
  resources :studios 
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
end
```

If you don't already, you need to define a SessionsController.

```rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def destroy
    # insert logic that actually logs them out, the below may already be enough 
    # for this purpose though
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged Out Successfully"
  end

end
```

When the user clicks "Logout" it gets routed to the `SessionsController#destroy` action which redirects them to the root URL (`'static#welcome'`)

There is more to it then that (i.e. the views and all that jazz) but this should be helpful enough